# HttpClientHandler (.NET Core) raise error when WebRequestHandler (.NET Framework 4.6.1) works as expected

Tags: authentication, .net-core, ssl-certificate, httpclient

I am migrating an application from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET 5. In the old application, I have a functionality that sends a request, using a certificate, an user and a password and it works just fine with **WebRequestHandler**.

Since in .NET Core this is not available anymore, I had to replace it with **HttpClientHandler** and I receive the following error:  *Authentication failed. The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.*

Can someone help me?

Here is my initial code:

```
            WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();

            X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate(certificateThumbprint);
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);  
    
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client .DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("segment", segment);

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            HttpResponseMessage userExistsResponse = await client.GetAsync($"Users?filter=...");
```

Here is the code that is not working:

```
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;

        X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate(certificateThumbprint);
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);            
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("segment", segment);
        
        var byteArray = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes($"{userName}:{password}");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
       
         var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, client.BaseAddress + "/Users?filter=...");
         var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: Post the actual, full exception text, not just part of the message. There's nothing wrong with HttpClient, although this code has several, unrelated problems. Perhaps the old code covered up certificate errors? Perhaps the old code *didn't* use TLS1.2 ? Perhaps the *server* uses TLS1.3 so hard-coding the SSL version causes a problem?

Comment: You can get the full exception text with `Exception.ToString()`. Post the *entire* text. That includes any inner exceptions and the stack trace that shows where the exception was thrown and which chain of calls caused it. This will show if this was raised due to eg certificate validation.

Comment: As for the other problems: HttpClient is thread-safe and *meant* to be reused. Not doing so wastes OS sockets, which can lead to starvation and crashes. You only need to change the `request` each time. You should use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of creating a new Encoding instance each time. That just wastes time and RAM. You don't need `client.BaseAddress + "/Users?` to create the URL when you've already specified the base address. `handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;` *prevents* you from using TLS1.3 and up. Just remove this line. HttpClient already tries to use the latest TLS version.

Answer (score 0):

*I wanted to write a comment, but it's too big. So posting it here:*

Looks like a certificate problem to me. **In order to check this**, disable certificate validation:

```
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
   httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
   using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
   {
   }
}
```

If the request would work, you will know for sure the problem is with SSL handshake. **Do not leave code like this! You need to find the root cause and not disable the check.**

If my idea is correct, my next question would be: Is your certificate self-signed or a real certificate issued through a trusted authority?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried also with the Callback, it still does not work for .NET Core. The certificate is a real certificate, issued through a trusted authority.